# Proving $(n+1)$th differential is $0$ given lower differentials are $0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Following is a question I am stuck in.

> Let $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be an infinitely differentiable function and suppose that for some $n ≥ 1$,
>   $$f(1) = f(0) = f^{(1)}(0) = f^{(2)}(0) = · · · = f^{(n)}(0) = 0$$
>   Prove that there exists $x \in (0, 1)$ such that $f^{(n+1)}(x) = 0$.

It is a past question of an entrance exam.

I thought to use Rolle's Theorem, but this requires information about $f^{(n)} (1)$ that I am unable to get. Only information about behaviour at $1$ I have is $f(1)=0$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** Well, think small. For $n=0$ it is trivial. So try to think about what happens for $n=1$ first. The result would read

> If $f(1) = f(0) = f'(0) = 0$, there is $x \in (0,1)$ such that $f''(x) = 0$.

How would one go about this? Ok, if $f(1) = f(0)$ there is $y \in (0,1)$ such that $f'(y) = 0$. Now there is $x \in (0,y)\subseteq (0,1)$ such that $f''(x) = 0$, by Rolle's theorem again. Do you see the pattern?

Comment: Thanks...I was fixated on fiding values at 1 that I forgot to consider intermediate values...

Answer (score 5):

Since $f(0)=f(1)=0,\ \exists c\in(0,1)$ such that $f'(c)= 0.$  Now since $f'(0) = f'(c)=0,\ \exists d \in (0,c)$ such that $f''(d)=0.$  Proceed.

Answer (score 4):

Love the answers. Another method.

Taylor expansion: 
$$f(x) = f(0)+ f'(0)x+\dots + f^{(n)}(0)\frac{x^n}{n!}+\frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1},$$

$c$ is in the open interval between $0$ and $x$.